# Change theme per page or post

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Is it possible to change the theme for specific page or post?

Any recommended plugin for this?

Comment: http://wpmu.org/wordpress-different-theme-per-page-post/ should be a simple answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't display a *different Theme* for different Pages or Posts; however, you can create *custom template files* and *custom CSS* for given Pages or Posts.

Ensure that your Theme calls `<?php body_class(); ?>` inside the HTML `<body>` tag, and then inspect the classes output for the Page or Post for which you want to create the custom style/layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you need create a custom theme. Save a copy of single.php file rename it to whatever you want.

**Paste the following code there -**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Template1
*/
?>
```

Now you can select your template everytime you create new post. Hope i helped you

Comment: Refer this page too  http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: I wonder if there is a good plugin to do this, without coding.

Comment: there is a plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-file-maker/

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, since this is an example of creating a custom _template_ for a particular post, not a custom _theme_. Terminology is important here.